# Counter overflow or condition not meat

Tags: variables, case, vhdl

I am working on a small project of a 60 minutes timer on CoolRunner 2. I want to drive four 7 segments displays to develop my new skills in VHDL, I am mostly an analog engineer so if you got any tips for me in VHDL, I will be open to them. But my question is: I have four counters that together  count up to 59min and 59sec and then reset but my third counter doesn't increment (`counter3`). When I run the testbench it only goes to 59sec and then resets.

Below I have attached my counters code for counter 1,2,3,4. Can someone see any spelling mistake or obvious error?

```
--counter1-------------------------------------------------------------     
Process ( CLK1Hz,RST,SW1,overflow4 )
begin
    if (RST = '0') or (overflow4 = '1')  then
        Counter1 <=0;
    elsif Rising_edge (CLK1Hz)then
        if (SW1 = '1' )  then
            counter1 <= counter1 + 1;
                if Counter1 = 8 then
                    overflow1 <= '1';
                elsif counter1 = 9 then
                    Counter1 <= 0;
                    overflow1 <= '0';
                end if;
        end if;
end if;
end process;

--counter2---------------------------------------------------------------
Process ( CLK1Hz,RST,SW1,overflow1,overflow4,counter1 )
begin
    if (RST = '0') or (overflow4 = '1') then
        Counter2 <=0;
    elsif Rising_edge (CLK1Hz) then
        if (SW1 = '1' ) and (overflow1 = '1') then
            counter2 <= counter2 + 1;
                if counter2 = 5 and counter1 = 8 then
                    overflow2 <= '1';
                elsif counter2 = 5 and counter1 = 9 then
                    counter2 <= 0;
                    overflow2 <= '0';
                end if;
        end if;     
end if;
end process;

--counter3----------------------------------------------------------------   
Process ( CLK1Hz,RST,SW1,overflow2,overflow4,counter1,counter2 )
begin
   if (RST = '0') or (overflow4 = '1') then
    Counter3 <=0;
   elsif Rising_edge (CLK1Hz) then
        if (SW1 = '1' ) and (overflow2 = '1') then
            counter3 <= counter3 + 1;
                if counter3 = 9 and counter2 = 5 and counter1 = 8 then
                    overflow3 <= '1';
                elsif counter3 = 9 and counter2 = 5 and counter1 = 9 then
                    counter3 <= 0;
                    overflow3 <= '0';
                end if;
        end if;
end if;
end process;    

--counter4----------------------------------------------------------------
Process ( CLK1Hz,RST,SW1,overflow3,overflow4,counter1,counter2,counter3 )
begin
    if (RST = '0') or (overflow4 = '1') then
        Counter4 <=0;
    elsif Rising_edge (CLK1Hz) then
        if(SW1 = '1' ) and (overflow3 = '1') then
            counter4 <= counter4 + 1;
                if counter4 = 6 then
                    counter4 <= 0;
                    overflow4 <= '1';
                else overflow4 <= '0';
                end if;
        end if;
end if;
end process;
```

UPDATE 1: the problem seems it that Integer dose not accept and function so I have attempt to convert it to unsigned, but that's not going witch out problems.

Comment: Please format and indent your code.

Comment: Hope this helps you understand my code more

Comment: I recommend to write a counter modulo 5 / 9 with an enable input and an overflow output. Then you can chain multiple instances of this counter together.

Comment: Get it working correctly in simulation before worrying about the Coolrunner.

Comment: Hi Matin Z , I will grab soon pen and paper and try to draw it up and write-up a psudo code for it and see if I can make the counter work by it self.

Comment: Hi Brian , yes I have to acknowledge when I try to make test bench for it my states and the outputs would not change , I thing I have to start braking the code to smaller bits and see if each preforms as I want it to.

Comment: Hi guys thanks for good advice I have rewritten the whole code and done proper test bench for it. Now the code works pretty well but I only counts to 60 some how the third counter that increments minutes doesn't increment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Counter 3 is not incrementing because `overflow2` is never set to '1'. Let's take a look on the clock-synchronous part of the process for `counter2`:

```
    if (SW1 = '1' ) and (overflow1 = '1') then
        counter2 <= counter2 + 1;
            if counter2 = 5 and counter1 = 8 then
                overflow2 <= '1';
            elsif counter2 = 5 and counter1 = 9 then
                counter2 <= 0;
                overflow2 <= '0';
            end if;
    end if;
```

The register `overflow2` is only set, when `SW = '1'`, `overflow1 = '1'`, `counter2 = 5` and `counter1 = '8'`. But, `overflow1 = '1'` and `counter1 = 8` are never true at the same time. The register `overflow1` is set when the old value of `counter1` is 8, but then `overflow1` will be '1' **only** together with `counter1 = 9`.

You have to fix the nesting of the `if` statements in this process, so that, only the increment of `counter2` depends on `overflow1`. Setting `overflow2` must only depend on the counter states (and `SW1`). So, the above has to be changed to:

```
  if (SW1 = '1' ) then
    if (overflow1 = '1') then
      counter2 <= counter2 + 1;
    end if;

    if counter2 = 5 and counter1 = 8 then
      overflow2 <= '1';
    elsif counter2 = 5 and counter1 = 9 then
      counter2 <= 0;
      overflow2 <= '0';
    end if;
  end if;
```

Same applies for the processes for `counter3` and `counter4`.

In the last process, the signal `overflow4` can only be set, because once it is set, the asynchronous reset will be executed forever. Just use the synchronous reset of `counter4` as you already described. `overflow4` should also reset the other counters **synchronously**, but I will leave this an exercise.

Putting, this all together, you will get the following code embedded into a testbench with a clock generation:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity counter2 is
end entity counter2;

architecture counter2 of counter2 is
  signal counter1, counter2, counter3, counter4 : integer := 0;
  signal overflow1, overflow2, overflow3, overflow4 : std_logic := '0';
  signal RST : std_logic := '1';
  signal SW1 : std_logic := '1';
  signal CLK1Hz : std_logic := '1';

begin  -- architecture counter2

  -- clock generation
  CLK1Hz <= not CLK1Hz after 500 ms;

--counter1-------------------------------------------------------------     
  Process ( CLK1Hz,RST,SW1,overflow4 )
  begin
    if (RST = '0') or (overflow4 = '1')  then
      Counter1 <=0;
    elsif Rising_edge (CLK1Hz)then
      if (SW1 = '1' )  then
        counter1 <= counter1 + 1;
        if Counter1 = 8 then
          overflow1 <= '1';
        elsif counter1 = 9 then
          Counter1 <= 0;
          overflow1 <= '0';
        end if;
      end if;
    end if;
  end process;

--counter2---------------------------------------------------------------
  Process ( CLK1Hz,RST,SW1,overflow1,overflow4,counter1 )
  begin
    if (RST = '0') or (overflow4 = '1') then
      Counter2 <=0;
    elsif Rising_edge (CLK1Hz) then
      if (SW1 = '1' ) then
        if (overflow1 = '1') then
          counter2 <= counter2 + 1;
        end if;
        if counter2 = 5 and counter1 = 8 then
          overflow2 <= '1';
        elsif counter2 = 5 and counter1 = 9 then
          counter2 <= 0;
          overflow2 <= '0';
        end if;
      end if;     
    end if;
  end process;

--counter3----------------------------------------------------------------   
  Process ( CLK1Hz,RST,SW1,overflow2,overflow4,counter1,counter2 )
  begin
    if (RST = '0') or (overflow4 = '1') then
      Counter3 <=0;
    elsif Rising_edge (CLK1Hz) then
      if (SW1 = '1' ) then
        if (overflow2 = '1') then
          counter3 <= counter3 + 1;
        end if;

        if counter3 = 9 and counter2 = 5 and counter1 = 8 then
          overflow3 <= '1';
        elsif counter3 = 9 and counter2 = 5 and counter1 = 9 then
          counter3 <= 0;
          overflow3 <= '0';
        end if;
      end if;
    end if;
  end process;    

--counter4----------------------------------------------------------------
  Process ( CLK1Hz,RST,SW1,overflow3,overflow4,counter1,counter2,counter3 )
  begin
    if (RST = '0') then-- or (overflow4 = '1') then
      Counter4 <=0;
    elsif Rising_edge (CLK1Hz) then
      if(SW1 = '1' ) then
        if (overflow3 = '1') then
          counter4 <= counter4 + 1;
        end if;

        if counter4 = 6 then
          counter4 <= 0;
          overflow4 <= '1';
        else overflow4 <= '0';
        end if;
      end if;
    end if;
  end process;

end architecture counter2;
```

The following is a screenshot of the simulation of the first 100 seconds:

[image: simualtion output]

Comment: Hi thank you for your response and all the error correction , its nice of you. I have completed this  project few weeks ago more or less the same as you done. I have realise as well when I was doing test benches that my nested if were incorrectly done, it had to little time to execute. It was fun project to do just to come back to VHDL. Thanks again for going through the answer. I hope somebody else can also benefit from this.